# Python csv dictwriter how to avoid writing multiple lines if data itself contain line break?

Tags: python, csv

For instance, one of the cell is like this, there is line break inside the data.

```
           +- 'Join LeftOuter, ('A.CARD_CODE = 'C.CARD_CODE)
               :- 'Join LeftOuter, ('A.SCENE_CODE = 'B.SCENE_CODE)
               :  :- 'SubqueryAlias `A`
               :  :  +- 'Aggregate ['SCENE_CODE, 'CARD_CODE, 'PRT_DT]
```

**The problem is the output csv will be separated to several lines if the above data happens.**

How can I make them only one line?

The snippet:

```
with open('general_result.csv', 'a') as f:
  writer = csv.DictWriter(f, result_done.keys(), delimiter='|')
  writer.writerow(result_done)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to preprocess your data so there are no newlines within strings, e.g. by replacing them with a marker:

```
with open('general_result.csv', 'a') as f:
  writer = csv.DictWriter(f, result_done.keys(), delimiter='|')
  result_without_newlines = {
    k: str(v).replace('\n', '<NL>')
    for k, v
    in result_done.items()
  }
  writer.writerow(result_done)
```